# IHTMLDocument2 wait until loaded after click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mshtml

I have a method which automates logging onto a website based on the authentication's input names, their values, and clicking on the "login" button. Once logged in, I want to navigate to a page that requires that authentication. I have tried this implementation as so below:

```
private void authenticateWebpage(string username, string userValue, string password, string passwordValue, string submitButton)
    {
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webPage.Document);
        ((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item(username)).setAttribute("value", userValue);
        ((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item(password)).setAttribute("value", passwordValue);
        ((mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item(submitButton)).click();
        doc.url = "http://facebook.com/messages";

    }
```

My problem is that the url is being set to go to `"http://facebook.com/messages"` before the authentication is completed. Is there a way I can wait until the authentication completes before navigating to a different url? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what item(submitButton)).click() does. If the click triggers a new window, you need to handle DocumentComplete in that window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a Thread.Sleep(5000) should work in your case. 5000 is in milliseconds so it is actually 5 secs. You can increase the time as per your requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: That is if the login process is finished within 5 seconds. Adding more time to handle long load times for some sites would be undesirable if the page was already loaded